# Top bar icon after update to 8.1

Tags: 8.1

What is the last icon on the bar? [This link](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/what-do-the-icons-on-my-phone-mean) doesn't seem to have updated info.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That last indicates that you have unseen notifications in the notification centre.

Simply swipe down to read the unread notifications.